What does cascade do when altering a TYPE in oracle?
I am trying to figure out what does CASCADE in below statement is supposed to do .
ALTER TYPE test_cascade_type ADD ATTRIBUTE (col2 VARCHAR2(4000)) CASCADE;
I tried creating a table with a column of user defined type and then tried to alter the TYPE with cascade option.
CREATE TYPE test_cascade_type AS OBJECT( col1 NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE test_cascade( col1 test_cascade_type);
ALTER TYPE test_cascade_type ADD ATTRIBUTE (col2 VARCHAR2(4000)) CASCADE;
But only the TYPE was altered . Nothing changed in the TABLE.

From the ALTER TYPE documentation:

dependent_handling_clause
Specifies how the database is to handle objects that are dependent on the modified type. If you omit this clause, then the ALTER TYPE statement terminates if the type has any dependent type or table.

...

CASCADE
Propagates the type change to dependent types and tables. The database terminates the statement if any errors are found in the dependent types or tables unless you also specify FORCE.
If you change the property of the type between FINAL and NOT FINAL, then you must specify this clause to convert data in dependent columns and tables.

If you have the types:
CREATE TYPE test_cascade_type AS OBJECT( col1 NUMBER);

CREATE TYPE test_cascade_table AS TABLE OF test_cascade_type;
CREATE TYPE test_descendent_type AS OBJECT( col1 test_cascade_type );

Or an object-derived table:
CREATE TABLE test_cascade OF test_cascade_type;

And you use:
ALTER TYPE test_cascade_type ADD ATTRIBUTE (col2 VARCHAR2(4000));

Then you get the error
ORA-22312: must specify either CASCADE or INVALIDATE option

But:
ALTER TYPE test_cascade_type ADD ATTRIBUTE (col2 VARCHAR2(4000)) CASCADE;

Works.


But only the TYPE was altered . Nothing changed in the TABLE.

If you have:
CREATE TABLE test_cascade1 ( obj1 test_cascade_type );
INSERT INTO test_cascade1 (obj1) VALUES (test_cascade_type(1));

and you alter the type then test_cascade1 will still only have a single obj1 column but that type will now have two attributes instead of one.
SELECT t.obj1.col1,
       t.obj1.col2
FROM   test_cascade1 t

outputs:



OBJ1.COL1
OBJ1.COL2




1
null



So, you are correct that the columns of the table have not changed; but you are also wrong as something has changed and now the objects in the table can have an additional attribute.
fiddle
